# flurry in android ，what is the method "addOrigin" used?

Tags: android, analytics, flurry

I am use flurry as the android app analysis tools.
① I whant to know what is the method (FlurryAgent.addOrigin()) usually used for?
② I need release app on other app store except googleplay，and so I want to analysis the different channel situation，What can  I do? use addOrigin（）method?

Answer (score 0):

The addOrigin and similar methods are tools for developers who wrap our SDK with their own development tools and does not apply in this situation.

We do not have a built in method to determine which store the app was installed from. I'd suggest having a custom version number for each possible download source.

Flurry pulls the version from one of two places: either the plist (iOS) or manifest file (Android); or from a call to setAppVersion (iOS) or setVersionName (Android). An explicit call to the “set” methods will override the value that is pulled from the static files.